# How to add a button to the right of the icon in the left

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mahapps.metro, titlebar

I am developing an mahapps.metro application. My current Task is to add an NavigateBack-Button in the titlebar right next to the Icon.

I was reading this thread:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T576836/how-can-i-add-titlebar-left-a-button

But they are using devexpress and it does't help me because I am using mahapps.metro.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for is the LeftWindowCommands part of the MetroWindow. You can checkout the QuickStart guide where it mentions it.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <Button>
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_arrowleft}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Button>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i was searching for. Thank you.